# makefile error: doing first time kernel module

Tags: makefile

```
obj-m += hello.0

KDIR = /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-34-generic

all :
     $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
     rm -rf *.o
```

error is: Makefile:9: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below `Makefile` to build the kernel module. Comments inlined in the Makefile

There is an extra space before `$(MAKE)` in your makefile

```
obj-m = hello.o

KDIR = /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-34-generic

# Here the commands to build the target should start in the next line with a tab space
all:
<TAB>make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
<TAB>make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```